# How do I calculate the duration of a calculation in PHP

Tags: php

I have a calculation for primes. And now i want to know how long PHP need for this calculation. I've tooked two microtimes before and after the calculation and substracted it. But the result don't match with my observation. I have to wait over two seconds to get the result, but the calculated result says 0,004 ms. Why is that so and how do I get the real durationtime?

```
 $prim_arr = array();
 $start = time();

 for ($i = 1; $i <= 20000; $i++) {
   $result = NULL;
   for ($x = 2; $x < $i; $x++) {
     if(!($i % $x)){
       $result = $i;
       break;
     }
   }
     if (!$result) $prim_arr[] = $i;             
 }

 $end = time();
 echo (($end - $start)/1000)." ms";

 print_r($prim_arr);
```

Comment: You can use [microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)

Comment: Others have answered the issue regarding time()/microtime(). Your method for finding primes is very naive. You only need to iterate up to int($i/2) on the inner loop. A Sieve of Eratosthenes will be much faster - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes. There are better algorithms for finding primes (mostly assuming that you don't need a complete set)

Answer (score 7):

You are calculating full seconds as [`time()`](http://php.net/time) returns the amount of seconds since unix epoch. Also you cannot divide by 1000 to get the milliseconds, you have to multiply. Use [`microtime()`](http://php.net/microtime) instead:

```
$start = microtime(true);

...

$end = microtime(true);
echo ($end - $start).' seconds';
// Or in milliseconds:
echo (($end - $start) * 1000).' ms';
```

What happened in your example was that you got two times in seconds, eg. `1314173657` and `1314173661`. The difference is 4 seconds. You then divided that by 1000 and got 0,004 "milliseconds", which is obviously wrong. Multiplying by 1000 gives the correct result of 4000ms but with poor accuracy. That's where microtime comes in handy.

Comment: oh sorry, as i wrote i have took microtime. but my example was a test i've just copied. i thought microtime() gives microseconds back...but as i read now on php.net that are just seconds WITH microseconds. That was my mistake. Thank you.

Comment: Yup, `microtime()` can be confusing as one could expect to get microseconds out of it. In that case your calculation would have been valid.

Answer (score 1):

[time()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) gives you seconds. Why are you are dividing it into 1000 at the end.

If you want to calculate ms, you should multiply with 1000 or use [microtime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you need the time in ms, you shouldn't divide by 1000, but multiply.

The time() function returns the value in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

`time` gives you seconds. Try [`microtime(true)`](http://www.php.net/microtime) to get actual microseconds as float.